# Change link style when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is working fine, but now I need to change the color of the link that was clicked, so users can know which one is selected.

When clicked shoud be class="class_active", and all others shoud be class="class_inactive".

I've tried to add the code below, but it doesn't change the others link's class.

What is wrong?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/drix76/h6cj9/)

=============================

## JS

```
$(function () {
    $('.dis-content div').hide()
    $('.dis-content .area1').show()
    $(".dis-nav a").click(function (e) {
        //TRIED TO DO THIS;
        //$(this).toggleClass('class_active');
        //$(this).toggleClass('class_inactive');
        e.preventDefault();
        var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
        //  alert(myClass);
        $('.dis-content div').hide();
        $(".dis-content ." + myClass).show();
    });
    $(".dis-nav #show-all").click(function (e) {
        $('.dis-content div').show()
    });
});
```

=============================

## HTML

```
<div class="dis-nav button">
<a href="#" id="area1" class="class_active">Firefox</a> 
<a href="#" id="area2" class="class_inactive">Safari</a> 
<a href="#" id="area3" class="class_inactive">Chrome</a> 
<a href="#" id="area4" class="class_inactive">IE</a> 
<a href="#" id="show-all" class="class_inactive">Show all</a> 
</div>

<div class="dis-content">
<div class="area1">
<h3>Firefox</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area2">
<h3>Safari</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area3">
<h3>Chrome</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area4">
<h3>IE</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a comment, there's no need to use `attr()` when pulling the `id`, you can simply use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id");`.

Comment: Thanks, James, but it didn't work...

Comment: As I said it was a comment, not an answer. `id` is a property of `this`, there's no need to use an expensive method call to pull the ID of a property using `attr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is what you need:

```
$(this).removeClass('class_inactive').addClass('class_active').siblings().removeClass('class_active').addClass('class_inactive');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6cj9/3/)**

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know the `.siblings()` method. Interesting. :)

Comment: The HTML `<kbd>` element denotes user input and shouldn't be used to decorate URLs. I've edited your answer. Please don't do this.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Sad face. It's so pretty.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to remove `class_active` from all of your links:

```
$('.dis-nav a').removeClass('class_active').addClass('class_inactive')
```

Then, you can add the class `class_active` to your current element:

```
$(this).removeClass('class_inactive').addClass('class_active');
```

Does this solve?

Comment: I couldn't do it work with the solution above. But thanks for help!